# Using purrr::map over lmtest::coeftest with the cluster argument calling a variable with the "~" symbol

Tags: r, purrr, standard-error

I am failing to iterate using `map` (purr package) over the `coeftest` function (lmtest package) when I specify the argument “cluster.” This argument uses the “~” symbol to call a variable to estimate clustered standard errors. The error I am getting is:

**Error in eval(model$call$data, envir) : object '.' not found.**

The error seems to be that map is failing to "find" the variable in the map object supplied. Would you mind please briefly explain how to correctly call the variable using the ~ symbol within a `purrr::map` iteration?

**Minimum reproducible example.** Here I show how everything works fine without the iteration and how it fails with the map iteration.

```
data("mtcars")
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)
library(lmtest)
library(sandwich)

form <- formula(vs ~ hp + cyl)

m1 <- glm(
  formula = form,
  family=binomial(link="logit"),
  data = mtcars)

# all works well here:

coeftest(m1,
         vcov = vcovCL,
         type = "HC0",
         cluster = ~cyl)

# z test of coefficients:
#   
#                 Estimate  Std.Error z value  Pr(>|z|)    
#   (Intercept)  9.0890128  1.7544879  5.1804 2.214e-07 ***
#   hp          -0.0413522  0.0081069 -5.1009 3.381e-07 ***
#   cyl         -0.6895012  0.1632085 -4.2247 2.393e-05 ***
#   ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

# failed iteration with purrr::map

data <- mtcars %>% 
  split(.$am)

m2 <- map(
  data,
  ~ glm(
    formula = form,
    family=binomial(link="logit"),
    data = .))

map(m2,
    ~ coeftest(.,
               vcov = vcovCL,
               type = "HC0",
               cluster = ~cyl))

Error in eval(model$call$data, envir) : object '.' not found
```

Comment: It's not really the second map's fault, you get the same error with `coeftest(m2[[1]], vcov = vcovCL, type = "HC0", cluster = ~cyl)`. The problem appears to be that the `coeftest` function tries to manipulate the origirnal glm call which is saved as `m2[[1]]$call` which is `glm(formula = form, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = .)` and the problem is likely form the `data=.` which is an issue because the current value of `.` using during model fitting doesn't exist any more.

Comment: Thank you for pointing to the source of the issue.

Comment: “~” is just shorthand for `formula`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for ways to make this work, I might suggest using `by()` from base R.  In the `by()` function, you can subset the data, build a list of arguments, including data, formula and family, and then pass those with `do.call()` to `glm`.  Then, you can create the coefficient test you want and return the model and test.  Here's an example:

```r
data("mtcars")
library(lmtest)
library(sandwich)

form <- formula(vs ~ hp + cyl)

out <- by(mtcars, list(mtcars$am), \(x){
  args <- list(formula = form, 
       family = binomial(link="logit"), 
       data = x)
  m <- do.call(glm, args)
  tst <- coeftest(m, vcov=vcovCL, type="HC0", cluster=~cyl)
  list(model = m, test = tst)
})
```

```r
lapply(out, "[", "test")
#> $`0`
#> $`0`$test
#> 
#> z test of coefficients:
#> 
#>                Estimate  Std. Error    z value  Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept)  1.7018e+02  6.1237e+00     27.791 < 2.2e-16 ***
#> hp          -1.6003e-02  2.0194e-07 -79247.830 < 2.2e-16 ***
#> cyl         -2.4043e+01  8.6601e-01    -27.762 < 2.2e-16 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> 
#> 
#> $`1`
#> $`1`$test
#> 
#> z test of coefficients:
#> 
#>                Estimate  Std. Error     z value  Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept)  4.4251e+01  2.4495e+00  1.8066e+01 < 2.2e-16 ***
#> hp          -2.3612e-02  6.1130e-16 -3.8625e+13 < 2.2e-16 ***
#> cyl         -1.0070e+01  6.1237e-01 -1.6444e+01 < 2.2e-16 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. I just changed the "\" to "function" and works like a charm.

Comment: Yes, as of R 4.1.0, `\(x)` is shorthand for `function(x)`.